# carburetor Leaking gas oil mix when fuel lines replaced

Tags: engine, carburetor, small-engine, fuel-line

***Disclaimer*** I know this is for a blower not an engine, but was not sure where exactly to pose the ?

I'm trying to assemble the fuel lines for the Ryobi BP42 two cycle blower, someone else took it apart so I did not see where all the lines ran before dis-assembly.  But I found this image
[image: Fuel LInes] 
which my only question is....my carburetor is vertical where-as this one is horizontal....so that would mean that the fuel line would connect to the carburetor on the bottom (the curved insert on the carburetor). Is that correct?

Reason I am asking for clarification is that I did this set-up but when I was attaching the carburetor and the filter cover back to the blower itself the fuel line hose was just constantly dripping out the gas/oil mix from the carburetor.  It was like the fluids were just running freely into the carburetor with no restrictions, so I wanted to verify my connections were accurate and if so, then ask where next to begin to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Your question is on-topic here at MVM&R. This is for a carb on an ICE, which means it fits in just peachy. Thanks for coming back and asking the question!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - what is ICE?

Comment: ICE - Internal Combustion Engine

Comment: Ah - learn something new everyday.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: I was in a similar situation. this diagram helped me. thank you!